# NPM Error while installing Cordova

Tags: cordova, npm

[image]

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Is this on a corporate network? I think your proxy server is preventing this.

Comment: No ,i am sharing my Mobile data

Comment: run command prompt as admin or with admin rights.

Comment: I tried same but not working

Comment: @RameshThangaraj Just see if you get some help from https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/10791

Comment: I would suggest you also post the text version of the error output to make this search-friendly.